# spring boot app works, if packaged as war, but not as jar

Tags: spring-boot, jar, war

I migrated my spring mvc app to spring boot. It runs fine now as standalone, as long as I leave packaging to war.
When I change only the packaging to jar, the application gives a 404 for any page. Apparantly it does not find resources then. Why?

```
Project
-src
--main
---java
---resources
---webapp
----pages   <-- here are my pages
```

my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.tki.webapp.weasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>weasy</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Weasy</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>






    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>nexus</name>
            <url>http://gitserver:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus_releases</id>
            <name>nexus_releases</name>
            <url>http://gitserver:8082/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jasper-releases</id>
            <name>jasper-releases</name>
            <url>https://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <context.path>Weasy</context.path>
    </properties>
    <developers>

        <developer>
            <id>...</id>
            <email>...</email>
            <organization>...</organization>
            <organizationUrl>...</organizationUrl>
            <roles>
                <role>Java Developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>+5:30</timezone>
        </developer>
    </developers>



    <build>
        <finalName>${pom.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <!-- <finalName>$\{project.artifactId}-$\{project.version}-r$\{buildNumber}</finalName> -->

        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


<!-- <plugin> -->
<!--    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId> -->
<!--    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--    <executions> -->
<!--        <execution> -->
<!--            <phase>package</phase> -->
<!--            <goals> -->
<!--                <goal>proguard</goal> -->
<!--            </goals> -->
<!--        </execution> -->
<!--    </executions> -->
<!--    <configuration> -->
<!--        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate> -->
<!--        <injar>${project.build.finalName}</injar> -->
<!--        <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-small.jar</outjar> -->
<!--        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory> -->

<!--        <options> -->
<!--            <option>-optimizations !class/marking/final</option> -->
<!--            <option>-adaptresourcefilecontents -->
<!--                **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/spring.*</option> -->
<!--            <option>-keepattributes -->
<!--                Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod</option> -->
<!--            <option>-keepclasseswithmembers public class * { public static -->
<!--                void main(java.lang.String[]);}</option> -->
<!--            <option>-keepclassmembers class * { -->
<!--                @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *; -->
<!--                @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *; -->
<!--                } -->
<!--            </option> -->
<!--            <option>-keep public class org.foo.**</option> -->
<!--            <option>-keep public class org.springframework.**</option> -->
<!--            <option>-ignorewarnings</option> -->
<!--        </options> -->
<!--        <libs> -->
<!--            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib> -->
<!--        </libs> -->
<!--        <injarNotExistsSkip>true</injarNotExistsSkip> -->
<!--    </configuration> -->
<!--    <dependencies> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>5.2.1</version> -->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--    </dependencies> -->
<!--             </plugin> -->
        </plugins>


    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- this must be installed into local reposotory (SqlServer jdbc) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- this must be installed into local reposotory (Oracle jdbc) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for json deserialisation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>

            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependency for jasperreports which is not on maven central -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependency for jasperreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.tki.hbci</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfints</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>

        </dependency>




    </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you see in my Application class, I migrated from a spring.xml. Could that cause problems?

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml") 
public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

The spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!--    <bean class="de.tki.webapp.util.HyperSqlDbServer" id="hsqldb" -->
<!--        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop"> -->
<!--        <constructor-arg> -->
<!--            <value> -->
<!--                server.database.0=${database.file} -->
<!--                server.dbname.0=${database.service} -->
<!--                server.remote_open=true -->
<!--                hsqldb.reconfig_logging=false -->
<!--            </value> -->
<!--        </constructor-arg> -->
<!--    </bean> -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.controller" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <bean id="defaults"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
      <property name="locations">
        <list>
          <value>classpath*:defaults.properties</value>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>                  
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.Column</value>
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.BusinessCase</value>            
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.Connection</value>      
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.LogBcLoad</value>       
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.LogTableLoad</value>    
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.Link</value>
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.Source</value>
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.SrcSchema</value>
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.SrcTable</value>                
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.Preference</value>
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.Preferences</value>
                <value>de.tki.webapp.domain.TypeReplacement</value>                                         
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer">allow</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
         <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
         <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Auto scan the components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.domain" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.services" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.services.report" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.dao.report" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.controller.report" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.reconcile" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.generator" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.dbclient" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.tki.webapp.util" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme1/" />


</beans>
```

Comment: u can check if your jar contains the pages by decompiling it

Comment: a `jar` isn't a `war`... If you change your packaging resource loading also changes (as a war has a different structure then a jar). Hence your pages become unreachable. Also you are using Spring Boot but are trying very hard not to use it most of your configuration can be doen by spring boot instead of configuring it yourself. Also you are using JSP those only work in a scenario with WAR packaging and not JAR packaging (as explained in the reference guide).